# ng-grid which table send event?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

After columns in grid reordered I need to update data in my controller to have it in actual order. I can use `ngGridEventColumns` event but how will I know which table send it (I have multiple tables)?

Answer (score 0):

I get it. After ngGrid initialized it's options populated with gridId which can be compared with id that comes in event:

```
$scope.gridOptions.gridId === e.targetScope.gridId
```